# Changing WordPress routing to load the same page for different URLs

Tags: permalinks, htaccess, routing

I'm converting an existing website to a WordPress theme. One of the pages is a gallery that uses JS `history.pushState` to create unique URLs for loading certain images.

E.g. page URL (non WP website): `http://www.good-deeds-day.org/gallery/`

URL for a certain image: `http://www.good-deeds-day.org/gallery/img-35`

I would like to preserve this functionality in WordPress. However, when loading the URL for a certain image, WordPress considers it as a different page and displays a 404 error.

Is there a way to configure WordPress or `.htaccess` so that when such image URLs are loaded it will keep the URL and load the gallery page, thus displaying the relevant image in the gallery page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using add_rewrite_rule:

```
function bones_rewrite_rules() {
    $gallery_page_id = 395; 
    add_rewrite_rule('^gallery/img-.*', 'index.php?page_id=' . $gallery_page_id, 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'bones_rewrite_rules');
```

Answer (score 0):

But from your description it's *not* an URL to a gallery, but individual image of one. I would guess it should *consistently* show individual image for such URL, regardless if it's served by WP back-end or manipulated client-side.

The easiest way to accomplish such in WP I can think of would be [rewrite endpoint](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_endpoint). It can rather easily latch onto existing permalink structure and it's easy to work with and modify output.

Unfortunately your format `/img-35` isn't endpoint-friendly, but if changing it is an option `/img/35` would work with endpoint perfectly.